# Can a thief change my Apple ID and password on a stolen iPod touch?

Tags: ios, icloud

I can't locate my iPod and I know it is being used and has Wi-Fi but when I try to locate it's saying incorrect ID or password. Can a thief change or erase your Apple ID and password? The thief picture has now replaced mine when I look on my girlfriend's iPod.

Comment: How do you know it's being used, and what version of iOS were you running?

Comment: Thieves can only change it if they know your Apple ID and password. So far, there aren't any known exploits being used against iCloud Activation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Apple. Like now.